# Can't show products on Magento 1.9 home page

Tags: magento-1.9, products, home

I'm trying to show a list of all products on the Magento 1.9 home page but all I see is "There are no products matching the selection". I've added the following block into CMS>Home Page>Content:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list"
        alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Tried adding the following with no change:

```
column_count="6" products_count="13"
```

I've also fixed the RWD problem described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049034/show-a-category-and-its-products-on-homepage-magento1-9

I've set the product to be Enabled, set the New range from Nov 2010 to Nov 2020 and I've flushed the cache. The home page still shows:

```
There are no products matching the selection.
```

**Update**

Added the category_id as suggested but no change in the result.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" 
        name="home.catalog.product.list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Here's category 2:

[image]

Comment: check the visibility of products

Comment: also you should assign them to a category root category or a category that you have

Comment: Visibility is set to Catalog, Search

Answer (score 1):

You are using a block of type  `catalog/product_list` and is a general product list block that is used to show a product list. If you are using this block, then you need to specify from which category, that you need to show products. Without specifying it, this general product list block will not understand which list of products that should show in homepage. So use this

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="7" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

If you need to show latest products, then the block that you need to use is of type `catalog/product_new`.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

for `version < 1.9`

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.list" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

for `version > 1.9`

Comment: I've added the category but am still seeing the same result. See update above

Answer (score 0):

Stock Availability was set to Out of Stock despite quantity being set to 21